# Unity quaternion lookrotation behaving oddly

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I am using unity to create an airline game. I made the takeoff code as the following:
`

```
    Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
    float thrust_x = 2;
    float thrust_y = 0;
    float timeRemaining = 1.5f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

   void TakeOff()
    {
        m_Rigidbody.AddForce(thrust_x, thrust_y, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(thrust_x, thrust_y, 0));
        if (timeRemaining > 0)
        {
            timeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (timeRemaining < 0 && thrust_y < 1.5)
        {
            thrust_y += 0.1f;
        }
    }
```

`
The timeRemaining waits for 1.5 seconds and then add to the thrust_y. The lookrotation makes the plane point in the direction of the impulse vector. This works impeccably with the plane as a cube. When I replaced it for a model, the plane strangely adds 90deg to the y rotation for no apparent reason.

Before running:
[image: before running code]

While running:
[image: while running]

How can I make the plane once again point to 0,0. Turning the plane 90 and -90 at the start does not work, which gives reason that the value is being set, not changed.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you airplane model maybe isn't properly aligned with Z axis = forward ...you could parent it under another empty GameObject, rotate that one and fix the models local offset rotation

Comment: So, a gameObject with rigidbody, and what rotation? Also, the script on the new gameObject right?

Comment: You can also add an offset rotation thru code `transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(thrust_x, thrust_y, 0))*Quaternion.Euler(0,90,0);`

Comment: Can you add that as an answer, cause it worked.